# Nvidia detects non-existent display

Tags: nvidia

I am on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.1. I tried the default driver for a while but the performance wasn't satisfactory so I decided to install nvidia driver. The problem is, nvidia detects two displays and makes the wrong display as default. I disabled it and saved the setting to xconf but every time the non existent display with low resolution is used after reboot. and I have to manually change the settings again.

Screenshot -

[image]

xrandr -q gives

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
TV-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1024x768       60.0 +
   800x600        60.0  
   720x480        60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   640x400        60.0  
   512x384        60.0  
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        59.9
```

xorg.conf reads as

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400 GS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I remember disabling this 2nd screen using xorg.conf in my last mint install. Can't remember what I did though. Should have written it down :(

Answer (score 2):

Added the following to my xorg.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "TV-0"
    Option "Ignore" "True"
EndSection
```

Problem solved !

Comment: Would you set your answer as the accepted one as it did solve the issue